Endless looping in Minimax

This function is perpetually returning the King moves back and forth, even if I apply a depth.
The above example is a mate in 1, but the algorithm only returns the King moves back and forth and never analyzes Qb7#. If I take out the depth, it will go forever.
Is there something in this code that I am missing? Or what concept am I getting wrong?
function minimax(d)
    if (d<=0) return evaluate()
    genmoves()
    local incheck=attacked(plist[pind(kings[side+1],0)],side^^1)
    if (mvsindx[ply+1]-mvsindx[ply]==0) and incheck then  --checks for mate
        if side==0 then
            return -20000
        else
            return 20000
        end
    end
    if (mvsindx[ply+1]-mvsindx[ply]==0) return 0  --if there are no moves
    local value

    if side==0 then
        local bestsofar=-20000
        for i=mvsindx[ply],mvsindx[ply+1]-1 do
            local m=moves[i]
            makemove(m)
            value=minimax(d-1)
            takemove()
            if value>bestsofar then
                bestsofar=value
            end
            return bestsofar
        end
    else
        local bestsofar=20000
        for i=mvsindx[ply],mvsindx[ply+1]-1 do
            local m=moves[i]
            makemove(m)
            value=minimax(d-1)
            takemove()
            if value<bestsofar then
                bestsofar=value
            end
            return bestsofar
        end
    end
end


return bestsofar needs to be outside of the for loop. it was returning after only one piece checked. needs to return after its looped through every move.
So:
 for i=mvsindx[ply],mvsindx[ply+1]-1 do
  local m=moves[i]
  makemove(m)
  value=minimax(d-1)
  takemove()
  if value>bestsofar then
  bestsofar=value
  end
 end
return bestsofar --OUTSIDE OF FOR LOOP

